# Preventing special characters in column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, special-characters

I'm looking for a validating formula, that should be applied to the first column of my list (an ID column).

I would like to prevent users typing special characters, like: '.', ':', '?' and so on..
I've found this formula here but it's not working for me:

```
=AND(IF(ISERROR(FIND(",",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("&",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("!",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("@",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("~",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("#",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("$",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("%",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("*",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("(",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND(")",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("-",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("+",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND(":",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND(";",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("[",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("]",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND(".",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("/",
[ColumnName])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("\",
[ColumnName])),TRUE))
```

It keeps saying: Something went wrong
Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance,
Luca

Answer (score 0):

```
= AND(IF(ISERROR(FIND("~",RandomField)),TRUE),
    AND(IF(ISERROR(FIND("@",RandomField)),TRUE),
        AND(IF(ISERROR(FIND("!",RandomField)),TRUE),
            AND(IF(ISERROR(FIND(",",RandomField)),TRUE),
                IF(ISERROR(FIND("&",RandomField)),TRUE)))))
```

The AND() function takes two parameters, so you need to nest multiple AND clauses like the example I have given you.

I hope this helps.